# Как сделать чтобы для Windows работала только встроенная видеокарта?

Tags: windows, железо, видеокарта

Как сделать чтобы для Windows 10 работала только встроенная видеокарта, а при необходимости в других приложениях включалась дискретная? Просто раньше у меня так и было, и дискретная видеокарта не нагружалась в виндовсе.

Comment: Amd у вас или Nvidia?

Comment: У меня Nvidia, ПК

Answer (score 0):

В БИОС есть настройка Graphic mode. В зависимости от версии БИОС там могут быть варианты, включая Discrete, то есть только дискретная. В этом случае система «не будет знать» о существовании встроенной карты.

Вот [статья](https://club.dns-shop.ru/laptop/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-Nvidia-Optimus-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA/#top), там про ноутбуки правда, но не велика разница!

Answer (score 0):

Может помочь настройка производительности в меню электропитания, а так же уровень производительности в программе от nvidia.

Answer (score 0):

Не надо в биосе ничего менять. Если монитор подключен к дискретной видеокарте, то она в любом случае будет работать. Без нагрузки, например просто открыт рабочий стол, у вас даже кулера крутиться на ней не будут, а потребление будет сводиться к "нулю". Если сильно переживаете, то единственный фактор который влияет на то, как скоро сгорит ваша видеокарта, то это ток который течет по ней, снизте напряжение с помощью Afterburner, например, и будет вам счастье.